# KASAN config in 32 bits architecture?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, compiling

I am trying to compile linux kernel (version 4.4) with KASAN support on a 32 bits machine, but i can't enable it. It seems that it depends on 64 bits architecture only.
So my question is about the possibility of using KASAN in 32 bits architecture CONFIG_x86 ?? Is there a relation between KASAN and 64 bits arch ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/dev-tools/kasan.html) says:

> Currently KASAN is supported only for the x86_64 and arm64 architectures.

Comment: I don't know how but I didn't see that line. Thank you anyway ;).